# In Typescript how to do I make a class definition available

Tags: typescript, amd

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to migrate an existing project. It's written with Durandal so makes use of AMD.

My question is how to make the definitions of Classes I've written available to other files for use for things such as parameter definitions or interfaces.

To be a bit clearer. I've defined a class such as

```
class Example{
   constructor(){
     //some other code
   }
}
 export = Example
```

If I want to instantiate that class I import it with require and thats all fine.

But what if I just want to use it in another file as a parameter type e.g.

```
function(value:Example){
}
```

Or in an interface

```
interface exampleInterface{ 
   value:Example
}
```

I can import it using require in the first example, but this doesn't seem like the correct way since I'm emitting code when all I'm doing is using the class for compile time. And if I use require in the second example, the interface is no longer visible to the other classes.

The only way I've found so far is to declare an ambient version of the class in a seperate file. That works but is an obvious duplication and a problem for maintanence.

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can import it using require in the first example, but this doesn't seem like the correct way since I'm emitting code when all I'm doing is using the class for compile time

This is the *recommended* way. Basically it ensures that the the file that has the class definition is *parsed* by the runtime *before* this file. Note that if you *don't use the imported stuff as a variable* then the code emit *does not take a dependency*.

See [**Import Type Only**](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html) for docs.

Comment: Thanks, basarat.. Just to clarify for any other noobs who come across this. The other problem I had with importing using require was that if I imported into an interface, that interface was no longer visible to other files. It looks like I was declaring the interfaces incorrectly. I need to explicitly export the interfaces "export interface Example", I can then import them in other files using rquire.